# disciriminative subspace Fisher discriminative analysis

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pca

I have only 2 classes.
Fisher Discrimination Analysis project the data into a low dimensional discriminative subspace. According to the papers, I can find atmost  C-1 non-zero eigen values. That means if my initial data has a dimension d the projected data will have a dimension of atmost c-1.
If the number of classes are only 2, I will get a feature vector with only one dimension.

My problem is I would like to project my data into a discriminative subspace and then I would like to get a feature vector of size m (m < d, m~=1).

Are there any way to do these kind of discriminative projection?

Comment: I was hoping to read the rest of this question but it looks like user570593 was struck by lightning or maybe attacked by a bear in mid-sentence. Sad, really.

Comment: Sorry. Now u may read it.